# Flying with the help of Coriolis force

Tags: coriolis-effect, lift

I had just started to learn about Coriolis force and an interesting thought occurred to me. Can you fly with the help of Coriolis force because when you run Coriolis force acts upward and the angular velocity vector is perpendicular to the relative velocity vector?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer here is no. At least not more that you can fly with the help of the centrifugal force.

Remember that both of these forces are fictitious forces, so there exists a coordinate system where the forces are zero.

Do not get me wrong, i like the way you are thinking. Unfortunately the scenario you are describing is essentially a situation where you are orbiting the earth in free-fall.